# Drag and drop items intra list as well as sort inner items

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Newbie in angular material, trying to solve a client requirement.
I found an example which is similar to my requirement with this link.

[Refer the stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop-child-groups-fxzjja?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.ts)

**Here in the example the drag and drop is working fine outer-list-to-inner list and inner-outer list cases. But the sorting within the inner list is not working.

For example I want to drag the item 'Walk Dog' before the 'Brush teeth' item directly. it need to drag the outside list then only I can drag it to there.
Can it possible to make it working? If yes how.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve? Do you need nested lists, but they should be sortable? The reason why this example works as is is because the template for the draggable item is changed depending on the item, as you can see from the ngIf on the inner div. If you only need drag/drop between lists and sorting Angular Material has working examples of that:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: @LarsRødal Hi buddy. Thanks for reply. Like you said, I want all the feature currently this example having now. In addition I want to sort the Inner item. Can I achieve this, If yes/no why?